# How do I batch convert multiple video files, using freeware?

Tags: batch, video-conversion

I wanted to use AviDemux 2.7.2 but the companion executable called **avidemux_jobs.exe**, does not execute the jobs added to the joblist in the main program.

So, this is not off-topic, because it follows the MANDATED pattern of:

"I have  that doesn't work anymore. How do I troubleshoot or fix this?"

But I can do that literally, since flexibility is apparently a problem on this site.

So:
**"I have program-x"** = AviDemux 2.7.2,  that doesn't do batch conversions **"anymore"**. As in: but the companion executable called **avidemux_jobs.exe**, does not execute the jobs added to the joblist in the main program .... anymore.  **How do I troubleshoot or fix this?"**

Awaiting your fair, openminded, response!!

Answer (score 2):

For video conversion, [ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/) is great, it is a command line tool, but graphical interfaces exists.

Now for the conversion of multiple files, assuming you are running windows some batch will do the trick (using **FOR /R** to run ffmepg in all files in a folder for example).

So for MKV --> MP4 conversion for all files in "D:/Test", something like the following code would do :

```
FOR /R "D:\Test\" %I in (*.mkv) do ffmpeg -i "%I" -codec copy "%~nI.mp3"
```

Please be aware that since you are only changing the container, no encoding will happen.

Also, make sure ffmepg is in your %PATH%

Comment: i know WinFF is a GUi for ffmpeg, but I don't like it because it is kind of limited and under-organized. Is there another one? As an aside,  i don't like Handbrake neither.

Comment: Please do not answer off-topic questions.

Comment: for one thing, he could disagree with you that it is off-topic, (or is that impossible, given your infallibility?)
For another, he answered LONG before you slapped your arbitrary, opinion based judgement on my question.